# Using Variables for Class Names in Python?

Tags: python, dynamic-typing

I want to know how to use variables for objects and function names in Python. In PHP, you can do this:

```
$className = "MyClass";

$newObject = new $className();
```

How do you do this sort of thing in Python? Or, am I totally not appreciating some fundamental difference with Python, and if so, what is it?

Comment: I'd be interested to hear why you need to do this -- I think there might be a more Pythonic way which doesn't require variable class names.

Comment: "am I totally not appreciating some fundamental difference with Python, and if so, what is it?"  Possibly.  Why do you use code like the above example?  Please provide a bigger example that provides some context.

Comment: Interesting, but I agree with TimB, I'd like to hear the use case for this.

Comment: there are no variables in python, just names.

Comment: In one recent case, I implemented two different subclasses of a class. They had similar different implementations for the same general work, and they had roughly the same API. I guess that's a strategy pattern? Anyway, I wanted to dynamically use one or the other depending on context.

Comment: strategy = dict(strategy1=Class1, stategy2=Class2).
stragey["strategy1"]()

Comment: I had a similar case where the name of the class to instantiate had to be found in a config file. The use of [eval] of @TimB was the solution for me.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Python,

```
className = MyClass
newObject = className()
```

The first line makes the variable `className` refer to the same thing as `MyClass`. Then the next line calls the `MyClass` constructor through the `className` variable.

As a concrete example:

```
>>> className = list
>>> newObject = className()
>>> newObject
[]
```

(In Python, `list` is the constructor for the `list` class.)

The difference is that in PHP, you represent the name of the class you want to refer to as a string, while in Python you can reference the same class directly. If you *must* use a string (for example if the name of the class is created dynamically), then you will need to use other techniques.

Comment: downvoted, because your solution does not match the one in the question. What he is looking for is instantiation of a class with a string.

Comment: Please keep to PEP8. Using mixedCase names feels somewhat against the values SO stands for.

Comment: Agree with the first comment, this doesn't work for a class name stored in a varible

Comment: It works for the OP, that is why he has accepted this answer @Matt .
Also it works for me.

Comment: @reggie,  thought he asked about a string,I think may guy who made question also solve problem with Greg Hewgill solution. Because, all class we wanna use must be existed already, he can import them to a as names to use, not a random string!

Answer (score 68):

Assuming that some_module has a class named "class_name":

```
import some_module
klass = getattr(some_module, "class_name")
some_object = klass()
```

I should note that you should be careful here:  turning strings into code can be dangerous if the string came from the user, so you should keep security in mind in this situation.  :)

One other method (assuming that we still are using "class_name"):

```
class_lookup = { 'class_name' : class_name }
some_object = class_lookup['class_name']()  #call the object once we've pulled it out of the dict
```

The latter method is probably the most secure way of doing this, so it's probably what you should use if at all possible.

Comment: Very nice, I am creating a handle for dynamic classes and dynamic fields. I did `classes = {'class1': Class1, 'class2': Class2,...}`. Now I can get the object with `myob = classes['<class_name'].objects.get(id=<obj_id>)`.

Comment: Great, simple trick. Was bugging 2 hours before I found this. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

If you need to create a dynamic class in Python (i.e. one whose name is a variable) you can use type() which takes 3 params:
name, bases, attrs

```
>>> class_name = 'MyClass'
>>> klass = type(class_name, (object,), {'msg': 'foobarbaz'})

<class '__main__.MyClass'>

>>> inst = klass()
>>> inst.msg
foobarbaz
```

- Note however, that this does not 'instantiate' the object (i.e. does not call constructors etc. It creates a new(!) class with the same name.

Answer (score 8):

If you have this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print "MyClass"
```

Then you usually do this:

```
>>> x = MyClass()
MyClass
```

But you could also do this, which is what I think you're asking:

```
>>> a = "MyClass"
>>> y = eval(a)()
MyClass
```

But, be very careful about where you get the string that you use "eval()" on -- if it's come from the user, you're essentially creating an enormous security hole.

Update: Using `type()` as shown in coleifer's answer is far superior to this solution.

Comment: OMG, no! The eval function is evil. Do not use it.

Comment: @TimB, I think this should be the best  answer if it is up to me.

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```py
newObject = globals()[className]()
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using dictionary to store the class to string mapping.

```
>>> class AB:
...   def __init__(self, tt):
...     print(tt, "from class AB")
... 
>>> class BC:
...   def __init__(self, tt):
...     print(tt, "from class BC")
... 
>>> x = { "ab": AB, "bc": BC}
>>> x
{'ab': <class '__main__.AB'>, 'bc': <class '__main__.BC'>}
>>> 
>>> x['ab']('hello')
hello from class AB
<__main__.AB object at 0x10dd14b20>
>>> x['bc']('hello')
hello from class BC
<__main__.BC object at 0x10eb33dc0>
```