# Declaring class name in variable

Tags: python, django, class, django-models

I am building a project and I am trying to declare class's name in variable before declaring variable.

But when I declare variable like :-

```
klassName = MyClass

class klassName(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

then it is assigning with `KlassName` Not the variable I referenced to it.

**Then** I tried :-

```
className = 'MyClass'
klass = type(className, (object,), {'msg': 'foobarbaz'})
x = className()

class x():
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

it is showing

> NameError: name 'className' is not defined

I didn't find any documentation of declaring.

I did follow according to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223559/using-variables-for-class-names-in-python/2875113). But none is seemed to work for me.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank You in Advance.

Comment: What's your desired output? A model with a name that comes dynamically from a string?

Comment: I am just trying to assign class name into variable before declaring the class.

Comment: But why? The three argument call to `type` is the correct way to go if the class name comes from a string but you haven't explained why you need to do this

Comment: What do you mean by `three argument call` ? And of course the class name will come from string

Comment: Calling `type` with three arguments lets you create a class with a dynamic name that comes from a string. It's more complex to do however, so is it necessary?

Comment: I did exactly like `klass = type('className', (object,), {'msg': 'foobarbaz'})
` and **class klass** but unfortunately, class name is assigned as `klass` not `className`

Comment: Can you provide me a link or any other source in which this phenomena is defined briefly ? Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a class dynamically you can use the three argument form of `type`. To also dynamically create a variable or module member with the same name you can use `globals()` to create variables dynamically

```
globals()['className'] = type('className', (object,), {'foo': 'bar'})
```

To create a model dynamically may be slightly more complex but you can use an abstract base class to define all the fields/methods on for convenience

```
class Base(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

globals()['className'] = type('className', (Base, ), {'__module__': Base.__module__})
```

Comment: But how can I use it with `class` ?

Comment: @Van not sure what you mean? If you want to create a class with a dynamic name then using the `class` statement is not really going to work

Comment: Can you please explain why it will create problems or why it will be bad ?

Comment: @Van why will trying to create a class with a dynamic name with `class` create problems or be bad?

Comment: Yes. Can you please tell why it will create problems ?

Comment: @Van it's not that it will create problems, it's just that it's basically impossible (or at least would be such a hack to make the result behave in a sane way that it would not be useful)

Comment: Ohh.. Yeah, Now I understand. Thanks for the Help